# Solving the recurrence $T(n) = n^{3/4}(^{1/4})+ n $

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I need to solve the following recurrence relation: $T(n) = n^{3/4}(^{1/4})+ n $. Obviously, the master theorem doesn't apply here so I was using the substitution method. I used $x=\log n$ and $F(x)=T(e^x)$. I was able to get to $F(x)= e^{3x/4} \cdot F(x/4)+ e^x$. However, the master theorem still doesn't apply at this stage. How can I proceed?

Comment: It's your problem if you're not allowed to apply Akra–Bazzi. In real life such constraints are not imposed artificially.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I understand. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just expand it:
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= n + n^{3/4} T(n^{1/4}) \\ &=
n + n^{3/4}\cdot [n^{1/4}+ n^{3/16}\cdot T(n^{1/16})]  \\ &=
n + n + n^{3/4} \cdot n^{3/16} T(n^{1/16}) \\ &=
n + n + n + n^{3/4} \cdot n^{3/16} \cdot n^{3/64} T(n^{1/64}) \\ &=
\cdots
\end{align*}
$$
We see that $T(n) = C(n) n$, where $C(n)$ is the number of times we need to apply $n \mapsto n^{1/4}$ until the answer drops below some constant.

I'll let you figure out $C(n)$, and so complete this exercise.

Comment: C(n) should be the depth of the tree, which is log(log n).

Comment: Right – that completes the solution.

Comment: I'm still confused about some part. Isn't $T(n^{1/4})=(n^{1/4})^{3/4}*T((n^{1/4})^{1/4})+n^{1/4}$?

Comment: That's indeed right.

Comment: Ah thanks I got it now. There was a skipped step